# Eradicate line breaks - javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have the follwing two PHP variables to build a string which when complete will be a url to post to Twitter:

```
$encUrl = 'http://example.com/wish/'.str_replace(' ','-',$id[item_title]).'/'.$id[wish_id];
$encTitle = urlencode($id[item_title]);
$tweetTo = "https://twitter.com/share?url=$encUrl&text=$encTitle&via=myTwitter";
```

Then within javascript I'm trying:

```
window.open("<?=$tweetTo?>","","width=600,height=450");
```

When the page is rendered though it breaks by adding a line break e.g.

```
window.open(https://twitter.com/share?url=http://example.com/wish/Antique-earrings

/11786&text=Antique+earrings%0D%0A&via=myTwitter,"","width=600,height=450");
```

The error is

```
unterminated string literal
window.open("https://twitter.com/share?url=http://example.com/wish/Antiq
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Have you tried something like `str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "", $id[item_title]);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Darren. You are also required to encode `$encUrl`. Browser or any other scripting language will not understand URL inside URL.

`https://twitter.com/share?url=http://example.com/wish/Antique-earrings`

The part after `url=` ( which is **http://example.com/wish/Antique-earrings** ) must be encoded.

Hope that helps. Please let me know in case of more issues.

Comment: @Darren If it could help then please mark the answer as correct. Let me know in case of issues.